# Shortcut in Notepad++ to switch between search box and main window (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

Is any of you know if there is a systematic keyboard shortcut to switch back to the main window from the search box in Windows 7 (either from Notepad++ side, or Windows 7 side)?

Of course, you could do Alt+Tab but you might not end up directly on the right window (you might have to do "Alt+Tab" several times).

The idea to use Win+ to switch between windows does not work because the search box is not recognized as a dedicated window.

Thanks

Comment: what about ESCAPE and STRG-F?

Comment: "Escape" does go back to the main window so that could work. Small limitation: it closes the window so if you were in "Replace" tab for example and open the search window, it is back to "Search".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy of Kard Nails:

> Press Alt+Tab twice, releasing the Alt key between. When you go back
>   to Notepad++ with the second switch, the search dialog is no longer on
>   focus.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Windows 7 (Spanish Version) at the office, and all I've got to do to hit the search box is to press CTRL + B.